# How can one JavaScript file include another in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to organized the code in my Chrome extension in multiple files.

What's the typical way to achieve this? Build tools which combine all the files together?

Comment: Where do you want to include your files? You can include all of them in the background script

Comment: For content or background scripts, you can just list them in the manifest in the order you want.  For scripts loaded by a html page in your extension, you can just use however many script tags you want, just as with a normal html page.  Combining the files could work, as long as you don't use the build tool to minify your code, which would look extremely suspicious.